# Heat-absorbing species maintaining ideal body temperature

Tags: survival, clothing, species

How would an otherwise human species' society or behavior differ if they were heat-absorbing* (*not* 'cold blooded' like reptiles) as opposed to producing heat, and they also require lower resting temperatures?

To narrow the scope down I'm concerned with this species maintaining their internal body temperature as, like humans, they could overheat and over-cool. However I'd welcome any other important considerations.

Some (not necessarily correct; confirmation or discussion would be appreciated) examples might be:

1. They wrap up in extra clothing layers in the heat to insulate themselves.
2. They shed clothing layers in the cold to avoid over-cooling.
3. Sweating would still serve a purpose to cool them down (?)

[*] *Apparently this caused some confusion.*

*Non-scientific: If a heat producing (warm blooded) animal took room-temperature water from a glass, swished it around, and spat it out, the water would be warmer. If a cold-blooded reptile did so, the water would still be room temperature. If a heat-absorbing animal did so, the water would be cooler.*

*More scientific: A (otherwise immortal) warm blooded/heat producing creature in a small, closed system would eventually warm its system to the point where it would overheat and die. A (otherwise immortal) cold blooded reptile would go a very, very long time before overheating and dying. A (otherwise immortal) heat-absorbing creature would eventually cool the closed system and freeze to death.*

Comment: If you want them to be more of a 'reverse' of humans, sweating could serve to heat them up. If they life in an area just below the freezing point of water, they could expel spurts of pure water, which would flash freeze and release heat.

Comment: @ckersch I don't need them to be a reverse of humans, just was trying to not treat them like humans where it wouldn't make sense to do so, or, to rephrase, have them differ where it makes sense to do so. The spurts of water is an interesting idea.

Comment: How does endothermic metabolism generate power for them to live?

Comment: @JDługosz If you're fine with a generic answer, "a chemical reaction happens in their biology that requires heat as a catalyst." I'd think the specifics of the biology and chemistry would be outside the scope of this question, as most humans who are alive or have live can't offer a good explanation as to why they produce heat, yet still take efforts to regulate their body heat; the 'why' doesn't change the species' behavior, just observable effects.

Comment: I think you need to rethink your term: (i.e. mammals are endothermic)
en·do·ther·mic  (ĕn′dō-thûr′mĭk) also en·do·ther·mal (-məl)
adj.
1. `Chemistry` Characterized by or causing the absorption of heat; endoergic.
2. `Biology` Of or relating to an organism that generates heat to maintain its body temperature, typically above the temperature of its surroundings; warm-blooded.

Comment: @Seeds ...It appears that I do. That's incredibly strange that the term _reverses_ meaning when moving from Chemistry to Biology.

Comment: It makes a lot more sense if you study cell biology.

Comment: It might also help to explain why what you are talking about isn't an ectothermic metabolism. (cold-blooded)

Comment: @Seeds Was my question saying "(_not_ 'cold blooded' like reptiles)" not enough? Are you suggesting that I should reiterate it later?

Comment: Except, at least as far as we know, "not cold blooded" means warm blooded... ec·to·ther·mic  (ĕk′tə-thûr′mĭk) also ec·to·ther·mal (ĕk′tə-thûr′məl)
adj.
Of or relating to an organism that regulates its body temperature largely by exchanging heat with its surroundings; cold-blooded. What I am saying is tell us why/how it isn't one or the other. Sounds like you ARE describing ectothermic.

Comment: @Seeds Did the edit clarify what I am describing?

Comment: Can I translate what you describe as "a creature which maintains its body temperature below ambient temperature?"  This would imply the creature does raise the temperature of its environment, but it has a refrigeration cycle to keep its body cold.  Or are you looking for hyper-exotic cases like negative temperatures which require metastability but permit energy to flow from cold to hot instead of the other way around?  The latter would make the creature completely unrelated to humans because of just how exotic the matter would have to be.

Comment: @CortAmmon While that's an interesting consideration, the 'how' or 'why' are _entirely_ outside the scope of the question; this is just about how the creatures would regulate their body temperature. Like a question about "how a society would react to invisible rings" isn't concerned about _how_ the rings work.

Comment: I ask because the approaches vary *greatly* depending on whether they are actively cooling (which means they are adding heat to the environment to keep their temperature down), passively cooling (which means they would open themselves up to environments colder than themselves, but insulate against warmth), and exotic metastable solutions (which break all rules of sanity =)  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the style of clothing would be very different - loose and flowing, so that they have a refuge from over-absorbing if too hot (think the kinds of clothes worn in desserts), providing portable shade or a layer of insulation from hot environments.  However, they can also more easily shift loose clothing to provide more skin access to absorb heat when it gets cooler - I would not assume they would only absorb heat through limited areas, so more overall skin exposure would be wise at lower temperatures.

Perhaps hands and feet might be more adapted to absorb and buffer higher concentrations of heat, for much the same reason they're tougher in us, because they are more likely to come in contact with other substances?  Kind of like the way our heads are a source of heat loss, because of the way heat flows in us.  Their heat patterns would likely be slightly warmer at the extremities and a bit cooler at the core, since heat is essentially flowing inwards from absorption.  They would probably try to keep their core covered until last, the same way we watch extremities when it gets cold... it's a trade-off between insulation against losing heat, and exposed skin for absorbing more.  Extremities have the high skin-ratio for absorbing, while torso has a high mass-ratio for retaining heat (so better insulate it).

Homes would probably be thickly insulated - they would want more equilibrium with a preference for cool, since historically its' been easier to heat up than cool down, and their physiology makes overheating a more direct danger.  The earliest would likely be based on caves, and they would prefer the insulation of stone or sod houses, since they are more likely to maintain a steady temperature.  Wood is easy to build with, but the ability to heat homes (first with fire, then with electricity) probably helped offset the lack on insulation for us more than it would for this people, who have no easy corresponding way to cool the homes if they get too warm.

Likewise, they might not prefer hot food as strongly as we do, having other methods of maintaining body heat (it's not the only reason we do, but it is one factor). They likely would have some, but eating food cooked vs raw might be more of a personal preference, or a seasonal one, than a general tendency.  This might have an unexpected effect on the healthiness of a population - one of the things cooking does is make the food safer by using heat to kill off bugs.  I seem to recall an article about tea originally becoming popular had an unexpectedly big impact on health because it meant people were drinking boiled water, which was safer.  Cooking food or boiling water does take effort, and letting it cool again would seem like wasted effort - so a population which would actively avoid extra heat when warm, and could get it directly when cold, might not cook their food often enough to realize the side benefits, and so might be more prone to diseases from unboiled water, or have a harder time storing food because they didn't make the same discoveries about cooked food not spoiling as quickly.

Socially, the rules of contact would be different.  It has been pretty common historically, for people to pile close to conserve warmth (which affects instincts like skin hunger and etiquette about social contact and personal space).  They may be less social, less likely to cooperate with each other - since physical proximity is a big part of most human cooperation, and likely one of the first factors nudging people towards cooperation instead of competition.  This people would avoid each other when cold, since they would be in competition and potentially absorbing each other's heat.  They might cluster closer to each other when the environment is warmer, but I'm not sure it would help the same way since any cooling of one warms the other, and heading to isolated, cool areas would still work, too.  Likely they would overall give each other more space and have less need for physical contact.  There may be a lot more to overcome to get this society started on working together to benefit everyone, instead of direct competition... which means slower to become a society, develop technology, and so on, since population density and cooperation tends to play a factor.

Comment: This has some excellent thoughts across a variety of topics I hadn't considered. I appreciate the thought you put into this, and addressing the question. Cheers!

Comment: @NexTerren - glad you thought it helpful, it was fun to imagine.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be referring to is a homeostatic organism with an internal temperature less than ambient. This is perfectly possible, but it doesn't mean what you seem to think. An example is any human living in temperatures greater than 100 F. People can and do this, but the metabolic requirements are high, and so are water needs to maintain perspiration/cooling levels.

Comment: The internal temperature is part of it, but literally their body's chemical reactions use heat instead of produce heat. Somewhere inside them they have a chemical endothermic process:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endothermic_process I know that's largely repeating what I've already said, but I don't know how to further clarify it. I *completely understand* this does not exist in life as we know it, but I don't believe that's a limiting factor to this site.